# Project Euler #29: Why is my answer off by 37?

Tags: javascript

I am working on [Problem 29](https://projecteuler.net/problem=29):

> How many distinct terms are in the sequence generated by a<sup>b</sup> for 2 ≤ a ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 100?

I have done a brute force solution with a filter:

```
var main = function() {

    var arr = [];

    for (var a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
        for (var b = 2; b <= 100; b++) {
            arr.push(BigInt(Math.pow(a, b)));
        }
    }
    //arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    return arr.filter(function(elem, pos) {
        return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    }).length;
}

console.log(main());
```

My program executes fine. Although the result I am getting is `9220` where as the correct answer is `9183`. What am I missing here?

Comment: it's actually off by 37

Comment: What's the point of `BigInt`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake Jaromanda. Edited.

Comment: try with a smaller set of numbers ... then see where you went wrong

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but i just ran this code in my browser (Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131) and this executed as expected and gave me 9183

Comment: I am using BigInt so JavaScript can handle the large values that are generated when doing high powers.

Comment: Are you on a 32bit system?

Comment: I tried with smaller numbers and it works accurately. Only when I use larger powers do the inconsistencies arise.

Comment: I am on a 64 bit system.

Comment: That makes no sense. You first generate the high powers (and lose precision) and only afterwards do you convert the results to `BigInt`, where it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: why does it gives me 9183 when I run the function on my console?

Comment: Chrome/Firefox give different results ... though, Chrome does think `BigInt(Math.pow(10, 100))` is `10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104n` - so, clearly chrome is an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
BigInt(Math.pow(a, b))
```

Even with BigInt, the expression *inside* it gets evaluated before it gets passed to BigInt, and Javascript cannot precisely handle huge numbers. The behavior looks to be browser-dependent, unfortunately, the problem is not sufficiently reproducible on every environment.

For a cross-browser solution, you'll have to find another method, like finding the distinct factors of each number, and filtering out numbers with duplicate factor counts. (eg, 2^4's prime factors are 2x2x2x2, same as 4^2 - filter out all such duplicates.)

For example:

```js
const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}
const primes = Array.from(
  { length: 100 },
  (_, i) => i + 1
).filter(isPrime);

const addPrimesToObj = (num, prime, obj) => {
  while ((num / prime) % 1 === 0) {
    obj[prime] = (obj[prime] || 0) + 1;
    num = num / prime;
  }
  return num;
};
var main = function() {
  const factorsSet = new Set();
  for (let a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
    for (let b = 2; b <= 100; b++) {
      const theseFactors = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        let innerA = a;
        primes.forEach((prime) => {
          innerA = addPrimesToObj(innerA, prime, theseFactors);
        });
      }
      const factorsStr = Object.entries(theseFactors)
        .map(([key, val]) => `${key}-${val}`)
        .join('_');
      factorsSet.add(factorsStr);
    }
  }
  return factorsSet.size;
}

console.log(main());
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you describe what you mean by finding all factors?

Comment: Do you mean 3\*4?

Comment: Oops, thanks, yeah, that's wrong, 3^4's prime factors would be 3x3x3x3, since we're exponentiating, not multiplying. Separate out all numbers into their prime factor counts, then filter out the duplicate factor counts.

Answer (score 1):

BigInt have sufficient (arbitrary) precision (support by chrome)

```js
var main = function() {

    var arr = [];

    for (var a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
        var p= BigInt(a);
        for (var b = 1; b <= 100; b++) {
            if(b>=2) arr.push(p);
            p=p*BigInt(a);
        }
    }

    return arr.filter(function(elem, pos) {
        return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    }).length;
}

console.log(main());
```

Comment: This answer is also correct. Although I am not sure why. How do the changes you made with p make the BigInt more accurate than the way I did it?

Comment: @Jerome because you made `Math.pow(a,b)` (with low precision) and cast result to BigInt. I first cast `a` to BigInt and then i calculate power by multiply BigInts numbers in `p` (and save precision).

Comment: @Jerome [CertianPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016164/860099) solution is probably faster (lower time complexity) and more portable (not use BigInt) because he not calculate powers but rather make prime factorization and check powers - check His answer as accepted

Answer (score -1):

Convert the array to a set, all duplicates will be removed automatically. Return the size of the set

```js
var main = function() {

    var arr = [];

    for (var a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
        for (var b = 2; b <= 100; b++) {
            arr.push(BigInt(Math.pow(a, b)));
        }
    }
    //arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

   var e=new Set(arr);
   return e.size()
}

console.log(main());
```